# SharePoint 2010 Rest API filter statement not working

Tags: 2010, javascript, rest, filter, json

I am trying to filter a rest query but can't seem to get it to work.

During my testing, the following statement works (no filter, a alternate way to get the item I wanted):

```
// sort the list desc and grab the top item
var url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectStatusReport?$orderby=PeriodEndDate desc&$top=1&$expand=RiskHealth,ScopeHealth,ScheduleHealth,CostHealth,ProjectStage";
```

This one, with a filter, doesn't work:

```
// grab an item by the report ID
var url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectStatusReport?$filter=ReportId+eq+'1'&$expand=RiskHealth,ScopeHealth,ScheduleHealth,CostHealth,ProjectStage";
```

I tried these too:

```
var url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectStatusReport?$filter=ReportId eq '1'&$expand=RiskHealth,ScopeHealth,ScheduleHealth,CostHealth,ProjectStage";
var url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectStatusReport?$filter=(ReportId eq '1')&$expand=RiskHealth,ScopeHealth,ScheduleHealth,CostHealth,ProjectStage";
```

When I use the filtered version I get the following results:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    alert(data);                        // returns [object Object]
    alert(data.d);                      // returns [object Object]
    alert(data.d[0]);                   // returns undefined
    alert(data.d.results);              // returns undefined
    alert(JSONdata.stringify(data.d));  // alert doesn't fire
    alert(JSONdata.stringify(data));    // alert doesn't fire
});
```

Any help is appreciated

Edit: I did test all three in the browser address bar and they all work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out I should have been using:

```
data.d.results[0].ColumnName
```

instead of

```
data.d[0].ColumnName
```

to access the data in the json string. I forgot "results" is only used when you use $top.

I still don't understand why JSON.Stringify was not returning anything even when the values obviously had an object: `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove quotes from field value in your url.

```
var url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectStatusReport?$filter=ReportId+eq+1&$expand=RiskHealth,ScopeHealth,ScheduleHealth,CostHealth,ProjectStage";
```